# MongoDB GSSAPI Authentication failing on LINUX RHEL7 with .NET Core 2.1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently running a dockerized c# .NET Core 2.1 application on Linux.

My application connects to Mongo on windows using CreateGssapiCredential and works as expected.

When I try to run the same app in linux it fails with the error “An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.”. Stack trace -

```
{
        "ClassName": "System.DllNotFoundException",
        "Message": "Unable to load shared library 'security.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libsecurity.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": null,
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.Sspi.NativeMethods.AcquireCredentialsHandle(String principal, String package, SecurityCredentialUse credentialUsage, IntPtr logonId, IntPtr identity, Int32 keyCallback, IntPtr keyArgument, SspiHandle& credentialHandle, Int64& timestamp)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.Sspi.SecurityCredential.Acquire(SspiPackage package, String username, SecureString password)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.GssapiAuthenticator.FirstStep..ctor(String serviceName, String hostName, String realm, String username, SecureString password, SaslConversation conversation)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.GssapiAuthenticator.GssapiMechanism.Initialize(IConnection connection, SaslConversation conversation, ConnectionDescription description)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.Authenticate(IConnection connection, ConnectionDescription description, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.Authenticate(IConnection connection, ConnectionDescription description, IReadOnlyList`1 authenticators, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnection(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2146233052,
        "Source": "MongoDB.Driver.Core",
        "WatsonBuckets": null,
        "TypeLoadClassName": null,
        "TypeLoadAssemblyName": null,
        "TypeLoadMessageArg": null,
        "TypeLoadResourceID": 0
    }
```

I followed the documentation here for linux - https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver.html#linux-systems&gsc.tab=0

and also the GSSAPI/Kerberos documentation here - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Docs/reference/content/reference/driver/authentication.md

This is the code that sets the connection -

```
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Credential = MongoCredential.CreateGssapiCredential(test@testdomain.com)
                .WithMechanismProperty("CANONICALIZE_HOST_NAME", canonicalizeHostName),
                Servers = servers.Split(',').Select(s => new MongoServerAddress(s, port))
            };

            Database = new MongoClient(settings).GetDatabase(databaseName);

            _collectionName = collectionName ?? typeof(T).Name;
            _collection = Database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
```

Nothing seems to fix the problem. How do i get this .NET core 2.1 app to work in linux with GSSAPI?

Comment: GSSAPI Linux supporting is not released yet. Check the next (2.12.0) minor release

Answer (score 1):

It should work in the 2.12.0 driver release

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you